# How to run a cronjob every X minutes?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I'm running a PHP script in a cronjob and I want to send emails every 5 minutes

My current (crontab) cronjob:

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /mydomain.in/cromail.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The cronmail.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$from = 'D'; // sender
$subject = 'S';
$message = 'M';
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
mail("myemail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, "From: $from\n");
?>
```

But I've not received an email in 30 minutes with this configuration.

Comment: your absolute path probably isn't correct

Comment: please suggest me right path my php file cromail.php is into root directory  - mydomain.in/cromail.php

Comment: Sometimes php-cli doesn't want to work just because you haven't set the current timezone in you php.ini even if you don't use date.

Comment: Is it `cromail.php` or `cronmail.php`?

Comment: cromail.php for testing only

Comment: Does the .php file have right permissions? The correct permissions would be `744`.

Comment: Is `php`'s path fine? Check if it is `/usr/bin/php` with `which php`.

Comment: yes @fedorqui php file path is fine 

*/5 * * * * usr/bin/php/ mydomain.in/cronmail.php > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @NitinNain permissions already 744 but email not received since 10 minute

Answer (score 206, accepted):

In a `crontab` file, the fields are:

- minute of the hour.
- hour of the day.
- day of the month.
- month of the year.
- day of the week.

So:

```
10 * * * * blah
```

means execute `blah` at 10 minutes past every hour.

If you want every five minutes, use either:

```
*/5 * * * * blah
```

meaning every minute but only every fifth one, or:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * blah
```

for older `cron` executables that don't understand the `*/x` notation.

If it *still* seems to be not working after that, change the command to something like:

```
date >>/tmp/debug_cron_pax.txt
```

and monitor that file to ensure something's being written every five minutes. If so, there's something wrong with your PHP scripts. If not, there's something wrong with your `cron` daemon.

Comment: i update */5 * * * * mydomain.in/cronmail.php > /dev/null 2>&1 Not receiving email

Comment: I used the command mentioned here as well, but it was not working because I had a return statement after it. Make sure not to end the statement with return and also a note, when new cron is created it shows "crontab: installing new crontab" message.

Answer (score 35):

Your CRON should look like this:

`*/5 * * * *`

[CronWTF](http://cronwtf.github.io/) is really usefull when you need to test out your CRON settings.

Might be a good idea to pipe the output into a log file so you can see if your script is throwing any errors too - since you wont see them in your terminal.

Also try using a shebang at the top of your PHP file, so the system knows where to find PHP. Such as:

`#!/usr/bin/php`

that way you can call the whole thing like this

`*/5 * * * * php /path/to/script.php > /path/to/logfile.log`

Comment: i update */5 * * * * mydomain.in/cronmail.php > /dev/null 2>&1 Not receiving email

Comment: Have you tried running the script manually and not via the cron? The problem may actually be with the script itself.

Comment: FYI future travellers - `CronWTF` seems to be permanently down. Tried to edit the original but couldn't.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run a cron every `n` minutes, there are a few possible options depending on the value of `n`.

**`n` divides 60 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30)**

Here, the solution is straightforward by making use of the `/` notation:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
m-59/n  *  *  *  *   command
```

In the above, `n` represents the value `n` and `m` represents a value smaller than `n` or `*`. This will execute the command at the minutes `m,m+n,m+2n,...`

**`n` does NOT divide 60**

If `n` does not divide 60, you cannot do this cleanly with cron but it is possible. To do this you need to put a test in the cron where the test checks the time. This is best done when looking at the UNIX timestamp, the total seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. Let's say we want to start to run the command the first time when Marty McFly arrived in Riverdale and then repeat it every `n` minutes later.

```
% date -d '2015-10-21 07:28:00' +%s 
1445412480
```

For a cronjob to run every `42`nd minute after `2015-10-21 07:28:00', the crontab would look like this:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
  *  *  *  *  *   minutetestcmd "2015-10-21 07:28:00" 42 && command
```

with `minutetestcmd` defined as

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
starttime=$(date -d "$1" "+%s")
# return UTC time
now=$(date "+%s")
# get the amount of minutes (using integer division to avoid lag)
minutes=$(( (now - starttime) / 60 ))
# set the modulo
modulo=$2
# do the test
(( now >= starttime )) && (( minutes % modulo == 0 ))
```

**Remark:** UNIX time is not influenced by leap seconds

**Remark:** `cron` has no sub-second accuracy

Comment: The `m/n` notation doesn't seem to work on my systems (Debian 9, Ubuntu 16.04). Only `*/n` works. For example, `5/5` or `4/10` give `Error: bad minute; while reading /etc/crontab` in syslog (in Ubuntu with cron v. 3.0pl1-128ubuntu2). Has this m/n notation been abandoned, or is it only available in some systems?

Comment: @mivk Thanks for pointing this out. This was a mistake on my side. It should have read `m-59/n`. Only a range can have a step size. (see `man 5 crontab`). I have updated the answer

Answer (score 6):

You are setting your cron to run on 10th minute in every hour.
To set it to `every 5 mins` change to `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /mydomain.in/cronmail.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: i update

*/5  *  *  *  *  mydomain.in/cronmail.php > /dev/null 2>&1

Not receiving email

Comment: @user3705511 You forgot to run it via php - missing `usr/bin/php` part

Comment: added 

*/5 * * * * usr/bin/php/mydomain.in/cronmail.php > /dev/null 2>&1

but still not receive email

Comment: @user3705511 `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /mydomain.in/cromail.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: updated but still not receive email

*/5 * * * * usr/bin/php/ mydomain.in/cronmail.php > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @user3705511 Than run `/usr/bin/php /mydomain.in/cromail.php` in command line and check if there is any errors, if no, than check if your path is correct

Comment: i uses hostgator any way to check ?

Comment: i think i mission username or simple error 
/usr/bin/php

Answer (score 4):

```
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

To set for x minutes we need to set x minutes in the 1st argument and then the path of your script

**For 15 mins**

```
*/15 * * * *  /usr/bin/php /mydomain.in/cromail.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: This does NOT run the taks EVERY x (15) minutes. It runs it on x (1) minutes after every full hour.

Answer (score 3):

2 steps to check if a cronjob is working :

1. Login on the server with the user that execute the cronjob
2. Manually run php command :

   /usr/bin/php /mydomain.in/cromail.php

And check if any error is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Try a crontab record like this

```
*/5 * * * * php /usr/bin/php/mydomain.in/cromail.php
```