# Crontab process to link a php file

Tags: php, symfony, cron, wget

i have a php file named "name.php which i want to run in every 5 minutes. I want to use crontab for this function. I have found a lot of tutorial but those all are really confusing to me. Everyone seems to use a crontab file and write like so ...

***/5 * * * * wget http://www.domainname.com/cronfile.php**

but i really did not get it. Suppose i have a domain name "www.mydomain.com", so if i create a php file name.php how it be directed by www.mydomain.com/name.php.

Can anyone describe shortly how i should run my php file using crontab or wget.
i am running my project in symfony.

Comment: You can check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740573/how-to-cronjob-every-5-minute

Answer (score 1):

(I'd comment if I had enough reputation to clarify if you are running the file locally - but I think that you are.)

Here's now I do it:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/cronfile.php
```

Comment: i actually have done that, but it doesn't work. i am confused, do i need to run wget or cron, in order to work this method, if so how should i do that ...

Comment: Can you run the script manually from the command line?  you may need php-cli installed.

Comment: when i try to run like localhost:8000/name it shows permission denied because before it should run it always need to login...

Comment: What OS are you running this on?  Are you able to run this script from the shell?  Mine doesn't use the web at all, just runs from the command line.  Like a shell script.