# PHP generate a random number between 2 sets in a time interval

Tags: php, random

I am generating a random number every 5 minutes:

```
$seed = floor(time()/(60*5));
srand($seed);
$random = rand(2,30);
```

I would like to randomize the number to either the value `1` or a number between `2 - 30` based on a 50/50 chance?

Is this possible?

Comment: first the 50\50 rand, then your other logic, have you tried this?

Comment: Do you also mean you will not be generating the same number at any 5 minutes interval?

Comment: "    Note: There is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is done automatically. "

Comment: @Perumal93 No, it can be the same.

Comment: @nogad I need to use a seed so I can get a new random number every 5 minute interval.

Comment: no you dont. each call to rand will self seed

Comment: So how will I add the 5 minute interval without a seed?

Comment: you have a whole bunch of answers below where you didn't comment about/accept, yet you posted this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42099518/1415724 and no idea what you're doing there and not responding to my comment about it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Calm down I respond when I see it what do you expect me to do look at it every 2 seconds?

Comment: Oh I'm calm alright. I'm just wondering why the other people who gave you answers were left in the dark.

Comment: You sound like you have your panties in a bunch. They were not 'left in the dark' I was simply finding another solution on my own and posted it. How do you know I won't get to responding to them?

Comment: ok well whatever; open up a chatroom. Like I said, this isn't a BBS service.

Comment: the time\seed bit is confusing, im not sure you know what a random number seed does. Can you explain what you mean by "how will I add the 5 minute interval"

Comment: @nogad I basically want the random number to generate every 5 minutes. That's it.

Comment: ok well that's noting to do with the seed. php will call this code once on load, and never again. If you want a page showing this number to change the number you will need some client side code. you could just write this all in client side code if thats going to be the case

Comment: Oh I see, so you're saying that the 5 minute interval won't actually work because it will only run this code whenever the page is loaded?

Comment: exactly, that time code you have does nothing. seeding has noting to do with what you want. php will run this once only no matter what

Comment: That is what he said. To run a PHP script every 5 minutes you would use a CRON job.

Comment: i assumed it was for a users view, but if not, then perhaps the answer is cronjob not js

Comment: Name calling will get you nowhere @user3574492. Please refrain from doing so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a cronjob every X minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740573/how-to-run-a-cronjob-every-x-minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$seed = floor(time()/(60*5));
srand($seed);
$random = rand(1,rand(2,30));
```

Comment: I think this does not work this way. The number 30 is very unlikely.

Comment: *"How about this?*" - Um... shouldn't that be an edit? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42099324/edit or is this your solution?

Comment: mind responding here? is this a solution or not? if not, delete it and edit your question

Comment: This is my solution.

Comment: *"How about this?"* - You need to take that out and replace it with: *"This is my solution"*. You're asking a question with that right now.

Comment: Yeah, which was intended :/ I'm inviting comments from the people on this post, any arguments for or against it will be helpful.

Comment: this isn't a discussion board. If you feel that's the solution, then so be it. If you want to open a chatroom and invite people, great.

Comment: Nobody said it was a discussion board, people can leave comments how they please.

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask questions. That is not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $x = rand(0, 1) ? 1 : rand(2,30);
```

Comment: why so overly complicated? why not rand(0,1)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. If the first `rand` returns a 1 then it will give you the result of `rand(2,30)` otherwise it will become 1

```
$random = rand(0,1) == 1 ? rand(2,30) : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply randomize between 1 and 58:

```
  $seed = floor(time()/(60*5));
  srand($seed);
  $random = rand(1,58);
  if ($random > 30) $random = 1;
```

2..30 are 29 numbers,  1 and 31 ... 58 are also 29 numbers  -> 50/50