# Created cron job to run every 2 mint

Tags: cron

I have configured cron job but it's not working.
I wanted to run the myfile.sh script for every 2 mint and below are my configuration in crontab.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   comman 
2 * * * * /home/ubuntu/myfile.sh
```

myfile.sh is executable and contains below lines of code

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u[user] -p[password] --single-transaction --routines --triggers --all-databases > /home/ubuntu/backup_db10.sql
```

Is there anywhere we need to add configure anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a cronjob every X minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740573/how-to-run-a-cronjob-every-x-minutes)

Comment: Just an update. You can replace the mysqldump with the full path "/usr/bin/mysqldump".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running the script at two minutes past every hour. As in 1:02, 2:02 and so on.

You can change it to something like

```
*/2 * * * * /home/ubuntu/myfile.sh
```

to run it every two minutes.

A bit more info can be [found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).